# When passing an object into a static function, one of its fields changes to a random number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, static-methods, corruption

So I'm working on a Unity/C# project and I have a class called `GridObject` and a struct called `GridRect`, which contains the static method `PrintX(GridObject obj)`.

**Update:** I finally tried creating a brand new Unity project and adding the bare minimum number of classes. Turns out it was much easier to reproduce than I expected!

Test code which sets up the objects and calls `PrintX()`:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CorruptionTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public GridObject gridObject;

    public void Start() {
        var gridObj = new GridObject();
        gridObj.rect = new GridRect();
        gridObj.rect2 = new GridRect2();
        gridObj.rect.x = 1;
        gridObj.rect2.x = 1;

        GridRect.PrintX(gridObj);
        GridRect2.PrintX(gridObj);
    }   
}
```

Here's my stripped down `GridObject` class:

```
public class GridObject {
    public GridRect rect;
    public GridRect2 rect2;
}
```

And my `GridRect` struct:

```
using UnityEngine;

public struct GridRect {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public static void PrintX(GridObject gridObj) {
        GridRect rect = gridObj.rect;
        GridRect2 rect2 = gridObj.rect2;

        Debug.Log(rect.x);           // prints 518506984
        Debug.Log(gridObj.rect.x);   // prints 1
        Debug.Log(rect2.x);          // prints 1
        Debug.Log(gridObj.rect2.x);  // prints 1
    }
}
```

`GridRect2` is identical except for the name:

```
using UnityEngine;

public struct GridRect2 {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public static void PrintX(GridObject gridObj) {
        GridRect rect = gridObj.rect;
        GridRect2 rect2 = gridObj.rect2;

        Debug.Log(rect.x);           // prints 1
        Debug.Log(gridObj.rect.x);   // prints 1
        Debug.Log(rect2.x);          // prints 518506984
        Debug.Log(gridObj.rect2.x);  // prints 1
    }
}
```

This demonstrates several interesting things:

1. The `x` field of the `GridRect` or `GridRect2` struct is being corrupted when setting the local variable `rect` or `rect2`, but accessing it "in place" works fine in the line `Debug.Log(gridObj.rect.x);`
2. The corruption only happens when the struct being accessed is the same as the location of the static method, i.e. `GridRect rect = gridObj.rect;` works in the `GridRect2` version of `PrintX()`, but not the `GridRect` version.
3. The incorrect value is the same for both the `GridRect` and `GridRect2` examples.

So I have absolutely no idea what could be happening here. I suspected it was a bug in Unity's serialization code but it still happens after removing that from the equation. The only thing that seems to have any effect is moving the static function to a different class.

Comment: struct are value type and static element does change

Comment: I would love to minimalize this but since it seems to only happen with this specific GridRect class I highly doubt it will occur if I try to create a standalone example. I included the operator overloads in case that has implications I'm unaware of. Adding my GridObject class. @JoeBlow I just meant I'm not well versed in memory management, otherwise fairly experienced. I want this struct to appear in the unity inspector so [Serializable] seems quite appropriate here, [as recommended by Unity](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/24/serialization-in-unity/)

Comment: It was being called in an event handler but I tried adding it to a component's Start() method and still got the result. I'm kind of hesitant to worry about the context because of the fact that the GridPoint.PrintX() version works fine in that exact same context, when called either immediately before or after GridRect.PrintX().

Comment: You should be easily able to post the two classes in question, and which ever routine calls it.  Someone might spot the woe

Comment: Finally tried recreating this in a vacuum, and succeeded! See updated question.

Comment: Hi @drsimonz  You need to tick an answer on this question.  Don't leave questions sitting un-ticked.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I haven't really learned the ropes on stackoverflow. This question is unsolved but I submitted the bug to Unity and they recreated it so I'm not crazy. I doubt anyone's going to solve it here, what's the best way to close this discussion?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try and copy the object into another temporary object?

```
public static void PrintX(GridObject gridObj) {
    GridObject tmpgridObj = gridObj;
    GridRect rect = tmpgridObj.rect;
    Debug.Log(rect.x);
}
```

I am rusty but I believe passing and object directly is just passing reference to the original object and not its value.

Comment: Structs and primitives are passed by value and rect is a struct.

Comment: I tried that even though it wouldn't logically make any difference. Problem still happened. I did discover that directly printing gridObj.rect.x gives the correct value, so copying the GridRect to a local var may actually be the source of the corruption (see code at the end of my question).